# InvalidOperationException In c# how to go about it

Tags: c#

I have made a quiz form .

This first form is welcome form that contains 2 buttons: register and start test.  When you click on start test the click event of the button runs this code

```
Quiz_interface obj1 = new Quiz_interface();
obj1.Visible = true;
```

to opening a new form for displaying questions .

Now the problem part :

If I add another button or image in this quiz_interface part and add click event with this code

```
result obj2 = new result();
obj2.Visible = true;
```

I get this error `InvalidOperationException handled.  Failed to initialize because catogory name was missing.`

What is the possible way around for this?

Comment: Without posting more code, I'm not sure anyone can really help you.  What is 'result'?  It looks like the error is happening in the constructor of that object.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that your "result" object probably doesn't have a "Visible" member to set to true.

Definitely step through under the debugger, and verify the correct line# where it's crashing.  If it's "obj2.Visible = true", then make sure obj2 actually *has* "Visible".

PS:
You're not trying to use performance counters in your code, are you?

Comment: If that was true, the code wouldn't even compile. Ir certainly wouldn't throw an exception.

Comment: No it's NOT necessarily true, svick.  Nevertheless, "performance counters" might be the better guess (for lack of a code snippet):  http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/VBNET/278653/278653/failed-to-initialize-because-categoryname-is-missing/

Comment: Could you elaborate? How could `obj2.Visible = true;` compile if `result` didn't have `Visible` member? (That could happen with `dynamic`, but that's not the case here.)